# Why does XAML image source property contain "/MyApp;component"?

Tags: image, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I'm using an image and when I select a picture using Properties panel I get the following XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="GameImage" Margin="8" Source="/MyApp;component/Assets/Icons/GameImage.png"/>
```

Why am I getting "`/MyApp;component/...`"? (Is there any better way?)

If I try to do `Image.Source="Assets/Icons/GameImage.png"` why does it not work?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is because your image has it's build action set to **Resource** (Which is the default).  If you switch it to **Content** you can set the source in your XAML like this:

```
<Image x:Name="GameImage" Margin="8" Source="/Assets/Icons/GameImage.png"/>
```

To set it in code you can do this:

```
BitmapImage tn = new BitmapImage();
tn.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Assets/Icons/GameImage.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
Image.Source = tn;
```

You should be using Content for performance reasons.  See this article for more detail: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

Answer (score 0):

Any content marked as an embedded resource is loaded from an assembly. Thus, usage sites need to know specify the assembly a resource is embedded in. In your case, this is `MyApp`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

BitmapImage tn = new BitmapImage();
tn.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Assets/Icons/GameImage.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
Image.Source = tn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
BitmapImage obj = new BitmapImage();
obj.UriSource = new Uri(mera_image.BaseUri,file.Path);
```

Comment: `FrameworkElement.BaseUri` works only for new Windows Phone 8.1 ans Windows Store apps; however, this request is about Windows Phone 7 app.